# Differential equation from physics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

How can I solve this differential equation ? 
$$y'= ay^2+b$$ ($a$ and $b$ are from $ \mathbb Q$ )

The actual form of this formula was $$g =\frac{k}{m}\cdot v^2(t)+ a(t)$$ (from a physics problem).

Comment: Set $v=\frac{m}{k}\frac{f'}{f}$, then $g=\frac{m}{k}\frac{f'^2}{f^2}+\frac{m}{k}\frac{f''f-f'^2}{f^2}=\frac{m}{k}\frac{f''}f$ or $f''=\frac{gk}mf$, if that kind of equation seems easier to solve. See solution methods for Riccati equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is separable.

$$\frac{y'}{y^2+c}=a.$$

The antiderivative depends on the sign of $c$.

$$\frac{y'}{y^2+d^2}=a\to \frac 1d\arctan\frac yd=at+e.$$

$$\frac{y'}{y^2-d^2}=a\to-\frac 1d\text{artanh}\frac yd=at+e.$$

Comment: Thanks you a Lot dude <3

Comment: @Isham: you are right. Fixing.

Comment: no problem Yves..